# How to run sidekiq in a separate different docker container apart from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, sidekiq, whenever

How to run sidekiq in a separate different docker container apart from application. We are using whenever for the sidekiq jobs, but the jobs are getting triggered in all web containers

1. How do we setup the web container (rails app) and the sidekiq workers to scale horizontally as well (preferably as separate containers).
2. How should we manage database migrations since sidekiq, ui containers use the same image
3. I am trying to use the following snippet, is this correct or should it be any different?

> ```
> version: '3.8'
>
> services:
>   foo-db:
>     image: postgres:$POSTGRES_VERSION
>     container_name: foo-db-container
>     restart: unless-stopped
>     env_file: .env
>     volumes:
>       - /var/lib/postgresql/data
>     networks:
>       - $FOO_NETWORK
>
>   foo-redis:
>     image: redis:$REDIS_VERSION
>     container_name: foo-redis-container
>     init: true
>     sysctls:
>       net.core.somaxconn: 511
>     env_file: .env
>     volumes:
>       - /var/lib/redis/data
>     networks:
>       - $FOO_NETWORK
>
>   foo-sidekiq:
>     depends_on:
>       - foo-db
>       - foo-redis
>     build: ./foo-ui
>     command: bundle exec sidekiq
>     env_file: .env
>     volumes:
>       - /var/lib/redis/data
>     networks:
>       - $FOO_NETWORK
>
>   foo-service:
>     build: foo-service
>     # image: gcr.io/foo/foo-service:latest
>     container_name: foo-service-container
>     ports:
>       - "$FOO_SERVICE_PORT:$FOO_SERVICE_PORT"
>     env_file: .env
>     networks:
>       - $FOO_NETWORK
>
>   foo-ui:
>     build: ./foo-ui
>     # image: gcr.io/foo/foo-ui:latest
>     container_name: foo-ui-container
>     depends_on:
>       - foo-db
>       - foo-redis
>       - foo-sidekiq
>       - foo-service
>     ports:
>       - "$FOO_UI_PORT:$FOO_UI_PORT"
>     env_file: .env
>     networks:
>       - $FOO_NETWORK
>
> networks:
>   foo-network:
> ```

Comment: is this the actual compose.yml file you are using? It doesn't seem like it is nested properly (ie. `foo-sidekiq:` seems to be indented more than it should)

Comment: Yes its formatted properly, appreciate any inputs on how to manage this

Answer (score 5):

Here's the list of things you should setup:

- **Images**

**You should have a different image for your sidekiq and web application**. That way, you can ensure `whenever -w` will be called only in the background (sidekiq) image, and not inside the web image.

*Example image: https://gist.github.com/cesartalves/69f6440b97c89e9dee6cfffbdf9b7790 (adapt to your needs)*

*Important points:*

- `apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron` - install crontab
- `bundle exec whenever -w` - running whenever
- `CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "sidekiq"` - run sidekiq as main process
- `ENTRYPOINT [ "./docker-entrypoint.sh" ]` - run cron in the background and other aditional commands you might need to do

To check if crontab is running, you can do one of the following after your container is running https://askubuntu.com/questions/85558/verify-if-crontab-works

About the "horizontal scalling", this should be done automatically if you have multiple sidekiq instances consuming the same redis pool - the more sidekiq instances, the faster your jobs run.

If by "horizontal" you mean being able to set up on which servers your crons will run, you could have multiple schedule.rb files, and each of your background containers should deploy only one of them to the crontab, by doing `whenever -w -f config/schedule_specific_cron1.rb`. You could pass the file as an environment variable.

2. **Migrations**

If all the application containers use the same database, have only one of them execute migrations. This will speed up your container starting and avoid any locking errors.
I suggesting doing that in the "web" image since you will have multiple sidekiq container instances.

3. **Gems**

All your images will use the same gems. Therefore, you want to create a volume to store them, to speed up their building process:

```
foo-sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - foo-db
      - foo-redis
    build: ./foo-ui
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/redis/data
      - gem_cache:/gems
    networks:
      - $FOO_NETWORK

volumes:
  gem_cache:
```

Inside your image:

`ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems`

4. **Orchestration**

Which container orchestration system are you using?

Dependecies should be run on this order:

1. Run database container
2. Run redis container
3. Run web containers and background task containers

Ideally, you should be using something which allows you to specify how many sidekiq container instances you want.

--

I think that covers the gist. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: 1. How do I build a sidekiq only image, do you have a sample Dockerfile for that?

Comment: Do you have a base image already? Add it to your question, that makes it easier for me to adapt it to your scenario

Comment: foo-sidekiq, foo-service is supposed to share the same rails app container, which I feel is inefficient but there is no easy way to separate the runtime needed for foo-sidekiq

Comment: I'll add an example: https://gist.github.com/cesartalves/69f6440b97c89e9dee6cfffbdf9b7790

Comment: You are still copying the entire app in the above Dockerfile Is there a way to optimize it

Comment: How do you make sure that foo-service doesn't run sidekiq nor whenever, what changes should be made to the Dockerfile and how should we optimize it

Comment: What does this mean "# latest two configs are not necessary", can you be explicit

Comment: "You are still copying the entire app in the above Dockerfile Is there a way to optimize it". As regards to the source code, no. You'll need an exact copy of the files need to run on both web and sidekiq containers. If there are parts that only sidekiq or the web process uses, you can alter the COPY command on each image to include only those. As regards the gems, they're already optimized, because you're installing them in a folder mapped to a folder and therefore, they will be cached across containers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214688/discussion-between-cesartalves-and-rpj).